# Is pst-spectra or pgf-spectra package compatible with ConTeXt?

Tags: context

In physics, the packages `pst-spectra` or `pgf-spectra` work very well in LaTeX to draw light spectra. But since I use ConTeXt, I can't install them, the compilation always finishes on "p**-spectra" is not found.
My system is linux-mint, LaTeX and ConTeXt have been installed with TeX-Live 2016.
Is there a way to install one of them correctly for ConTeXt ?

Comment: It's not a matter of installation I'd think, LaTeX and ConTeXt are different systems, so you shouldn't expect to be able to use a LaTeX package in ConTeXt, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141425/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14725

Comment: @TorbjørnT. in general what you say is true but pstricks and pgf are both low level code that work in plain tex and context as well as latex so in principle it could work (although it may be that particular extensions use latex facilities of course so don't work on other formats without some work)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for bringing that up, should have phrased that comment a bit differently. I know that TikZ work in ConTeXt (don't know much at all really about pstricks),  as I've seen it described in the manual. I looked briefly at `pgf-spectra` though, and that does require LaTeX as is.

Comment: Would you consider using Metapost in your Context file?  Writing a routine to convert a visible light wavelength value into an RGB colour is not hard in Metapost.